# Close PopupWindow upon tapping outside or back button

Tags: android, popup, maps, popupwindow

I want to close a PopupWindow by either tapping outside the window or pressing a back button. Right now you can tap anywhere on the screen and the window closes, and I can't figure out why. I'd also like to add a shadow to the PopupWindow. Thanks!

MainActivity.Java:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener{

LinearLayout mainLayout;

private GoogleMap mMap;
PlaceAutocompleteFragment placeAutoComplete;
private static final String TAG = "Main Activity";
List<Marker> list = new ArrayList<>();

Marker NY_MANHATTAN;
Marker NY_BROOKLYN;
Marker NY_BRONX;
Marker NY_QUEENS;
Marker NY_STATENISLAND;

private PopupWindow popupWindow;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //TODO:initialize startup stuff here:

    /*
    * layoutTest is the testing inflater for all popup windows.
    * here is where new popup windows will be added to the list.
    * */

    mainLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);



    placeAutoComplete = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete);
    placeAutoComplete.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {

            Log.i(TAG, "Place Selected: " + place.getName());
            LatLng latLng = place.getLatLng();

            //move map camera
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 11));
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Status status) {
            Log.d("Maps", "An error occurred: " + status);
        }
    });

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    try {
        // Customise the styling of the base map using a JSON object defined
        // in a raw resource file.
        boolean success = googleMap.setMapStyle(
                MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(
                        this, R.raw.style_json));

        if (!success) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Style parsing failed.");
        }
    } catch (Resources.NotFoundException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Can't find style. Error: ", e);
    }

    //TODO: DEFINE MARKER LOCATIONS HERE:

    LatLng manhattanLoc = new LatLng(40.754932, -73.984016);
    LatLng brooklynLoc = new LatLng(40.650002, -73.949997);
    LatLng bronxLoc = new LatLng(40.837048, -73.865433);
    LatLng queensLoc = new LatLng(40.742054, -73.769417);
    LatLng statenIslandLoc = new LatLng(40.579021, -74.151535);

    //TODO: INIT MARKERS HERE:


     NY_MANHATTAN = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(manhattanLoc).title("Manhattan").snippet("test"));
    list.add(NY_MANHATTAN);

     NY_BROOKLYN = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(brooklynLoc).title("Brooklyn").snippet("test"));
    list.add(NY_BROOKLYN);

     NY_BRONX = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(bronxLoc).title("Bronx").snippet("test"));
    list.add(NY_BRONX);

     NY_QUEENS = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(queensLoc).title("Queens").snippet("test"));
    list.add(NY_QUEENS);

     NY_STATENISLAND = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(statenIslandLoc).title("Staten Island").snippet("test"));
    list.add(NY_STATENISLAND);

    googleMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(new
                                                GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener() {
                                                    @Override
                                                    public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition cameraPosition) {
                                                        for (Marker m : list) {
                                                            m.setVisible(cameraPosition.zoom > 10); // <-- define zoom level for markers here
                                                            /**
                                                             * Zoom level guidelines:
                                                             * 12 = zoomed in about 90%
                                                             * 1 = zommed in less than 5%
                                                             * Higher = higher zoom, Lower = lower zoom.
                                                             * Confusing. I know.
                                                             */
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                });

    mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);

}

//TODO: handle marker clicks below:
/*
* current placeholder code states that all markers
* will open the popup_test layout.
* */

public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker arg0) {

    PopupInit();

    return false;

}

public void PopupInit()
{

    layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    ViewGroup container = (ViewGroup) layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_test,null);

    /*
    *
    * set x/y locations here:
    *
    * */

    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

    int popWidth = dm.widthPixels;
    int popHeight = dm.heightPixels;

    popupWindow = new PopupWindow(container,(int) (popWidth*.8),(int) (popHeight*.6),true);
    popupWindow.showAtLocation(mainLayout, Gravity.CENTER,0,0);

    container.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent)
        {
            popupWindow.dismiss();
            return true;
        }
    });


}



}
```

Popup_Test.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="#fff55250"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="match_parent">
</RelativeLayout>
```

Sorry about the noob question. I've been at this for a while and I just can't seem to figure out no matter how much I try... my biggest two concerns are getting the shadow behind the popupwindow and also closing it upon the press of the back button or tapping outside the popup window. thanks very much in advance. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to set Background Drawable using and on Outside touch `true`

```
popWindow.setFocusable(true);
popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable())
popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);
```

method by passing any `drawable`. Otherwise the whole screen is your background and tapping outside will not work `backPressed` will work automatically using this way!

To add a shadow to you `PopupWindow` the easier way is to put `CardView` as the root of your `View` in `xml` and change `elevation` attribute. To use `CardView` you may have to add a dependency it in your gradle file as well

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="4dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

    <!--YOUR RELATIVE LAYOUT SHOULD BE HERE!-->

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

You also have to add dependency in your `app gradle` files like:

```
dependencies {
...
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.+'
}
```

More details in [CardView and elevation here](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html).

 **THIS IS HOW IT LOOKS IN MY CODE**

```
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    // inflate the custom popup layout
    final View inflatedView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.pop_up_test, null,false);
    // get device size
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    final Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    //mDeviceHeight = size.y; //Not in use just comment it off for now

    // set height depends on the device size
    popupWindow = new PopupWindow(inflatedView, size.x - 50,(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT), true );
    // set a background drawable with rounders corners
    // make it focusable to show the keyboard to enter in `EditText`
    popupWindow.setFocusable(true);
    popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable());//This has no meaning than dismissal of the Pop Up Noni!!
    // make it outside touchable to dismiss the popup window
    popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);

    // show the popup at bottom of the screen and set some margin at bottom ie,
    popupWindow.showAtLocation(v, Gravity.BOTTOM, 0,100);
```

Comment: Where do I implement the SetBackgroundDrawable and SetOutsideTouchable? I've tried adding it above toe OnTouchListener and it did nothing. I've also tried removing the OnTouchListener and keeping the new lines of code and that did nothing.

Comment: Oops  I forgot one line `setFocusable()` I have edited my answer. Scroll to see. Also remove on touch listener. at all

Comment: DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics(); getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm); int popWidth = dm.widthPixels; int popHeight = dm.heightPixels; popupWindow = new PopupWindow(container,(int) (popWidth*.8),(int) (popHeight*.6),true); popupWindow.showAtLocation(mainLayout, Gravity.CENTER,0,0); popupWindow.setFocusable(true); popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable()); popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);' still does nothing. no errors or anything either -- tapping gives no response

Comment: let me try to figure out again

Comment: Thanks very much. Sorry for the noob questions,

Comment: Since I can not get and test all your code. I have decided to show you my code which works (check it at the bottom of the answer I have just edited it ) so please first sorround your code for making a pop up as /**  code here**/  so as to comment it off. The start coping and paste my code from the bottom of the edited. My code works it start by getting device size and initiate the pop up. From there I can get the solution because I understand well what I wrote.

Comment: Oh, it was my silly mistake! I was showing the popupWindow before I set the focusing and background properties. Thanks for all the help dude, mad props.

Comment: Huhuhu! I am glad you solved your  problem! @JaredPawlyzyn **Happy Coding!**

Answer (score 0):

I could override your `onBackPressed()` method in your `Activity`. That being said, if you press your back button this method is fired. In that method you can check wether the popup is showing, and dissmiss it if needed, like this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (popupWindow != null && popupWindow.isShowing()) {
        popupWindow.dismiss();
    }
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

You can implement the `dismiss()` logic also with some `onClickListeners` from the area's you want the user to click to cancel the popup.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use Xenolion asnwer for whatever reason, You can just create backdrop manually which goes over your whole screen.

Add whatever on top of it.
Add onclick listener on backdrop which closes backdrop and window.
Add onclick listener on popupwindow as null that will prevent from closing pop up when clicked on top of it.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/backdrop"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/popUp"
        android:layout_width="500dp"
        android:layout_height="500dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/backdrop"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"></LinearLayout>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

backdrop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // code to close backdrop and pop up
        }
    };)
```

// this prevents closing of the window by clicking on pop up window

```
popup.setOnClickListener(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had popups that would not be dismissed by either back button or tap outside on Android 5. I worked great on newer Android versions, just not on Android 5, Lollipop, API level 21.

All that was needed in my case was:

```
popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable())
```

Go figure!